# How to match a String with html Markup in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string-matching, html-entities

I am trying to make a clickable element that controls a sidebar. The html text of the element should be changed to either << or >> dependent on the Sidebar being visible or not.
I came up with the following code

JavaScript:

```
\$j("#id_button").click(function(){
    \$j(".sidebar").fadeToggle();        
    \$j("#id_button").html() === ("&lsaquo;&lsaquo;") ?  \$j("#id_button").html("&rsaquo;&rsaquo;") : \$j("#id_button").html("&lsaquo;&lsaquo;");
});
```

and the corrosponding html:

```
<a id="id_button">&lsaquo;&lsaquo;</a>
```

The code works fine when I use plain text instead of the MarkupEntities. e.g.: "left" for `"&lsaquo;"` and "right" for `"&rsaquo;"` However using the Entities dosn't work as the string `"&lsaquo;&lsaquo;"`can't be matched to what .html() returns.

Comment: Compare to what you get (use console), should be `<<` and `>>` (if you execute `console.log( $('#id_button').html(); )` than you would see `"‹‹"`). But better way: use a variable/flag to mark if sidebar is opened or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the arrows directly?

```
jQuery("#id_button").click(function() {
    var button = jQuery(this);
    var left=  "‹‹";
    var right = "››";
    // $jQuery(".sidebar").fadeToggle();        

   button.html() ===  left ?  button.html(right) :  button.html(left);
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/sosgunbe/1/)